# Why does jqueryui.dialog ignore the height parameter when the selected element is a table?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-dialog

When I attempt to render a `<table>` as a dialog window, my `height:750` parameter seems to be ignored; the content, over 2100px in height, forces the dialog to render at the same height, making the whole page scroll: [(example)](http://jsbin.com/anosuz/11/edit#preview)

Also, here is a `$("table").dialog()` call where the table is *shorter* than the parameter. In this example, the dialog shrinks in height to match the table cell contents, again ignoring the 750 height parameter. [(example)](http://jsbin.com/ukakat/3/edit#preview)

**Workarounds:**

Rendering tables inside a `<div>` tag seems to eliminate this issue, but feels rather kludgy:

[Short table + Tall text wrapped in div](http://jsbin.com/ukakat/2/edit#preview)

[Long table wrapped in div](http://jsbin.com/anosuz/13/edit#preview)

Also, here is my workaround where I render an empty dialog and then pull the table into the window as part of the `open()` callback:

[After-render workaround](http://jsbin.com/ovebod/2/edit#preview)

Is this behavioral inconsistency a bug or is this by design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem like opening a table dialog without regard to the height option during initialization would be by design.  My experience has been that jQuery UI components behave most consistently wrapped as `<div>` elements and it looks like you found the same result but as you said, that shouldn't be a requirement.

The default value for the height option on dialog() is `auto`, which should scale the dialog to fit the element.  It's possible there is a bug when a `table` element is passed to `dialog()` causing `auto` to override the height options at init.  I tried changing the width value in your first example and `dialog()` does respond correctly by changing the width but height does not budge.  I also reordered the options so height was first but that also did not have an effect.

JS Bin doesn't work well for me so I moved your code to this fiddle and condensed the dialog init call.  https://jsfiddle.net/z601hhjd/

```
// Open dialog and set height and width on init
// Width option works at initialization but height does not
$(".shortTable").dialog({
     'height':'300',
     'width':'500',
     open: function(event, ui) {
         // Height setter has no effect after init either
         $(this).dialog("option", "height", 200 );

         // Width setter works after initialization too
         $(this).dialog("option", "width", 200 );
     }
});
```

It looks like there is a bug in jQuery UI for setting the height on `table` elements which conflicts with the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-height) but this functionality is consistent with the HTML specs as @Peri said.

Comment: It seems unintuitive that the height parameter would be targeting the original element's height even after init, **especially** because this is inconsistent with the draggable resize control in the lower-righthand corner of the dialog; manually dragging the resize handle allows the dialog to be any height you wish, and the `div.ui-dialog-content` wrapper is the element that is changed when using the resize control. If not a bug, then a serious inconsistency.

Comment: I was building the dialog as `<dialog>` and I was experiencing this problem. When changed the tag to `<div>` it started to set the height correctly. Dylan said `My experience has been that jQuery UI components behave most consistently wrapped as <div> elements` and that's very true indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I find that jQuery UI tries to be too smart when it comes to specifying a height. It tries to discover its container height and do some calculations, etc. I've even had cases where the dialog would show correctly once and then get an element style height assigned in subsequent loads of the same dialog (with no changes to the dialogs config options). My opinion as a developer is that I don't like that "smart" behaviour very much.

So after a bunch of online research I came to the conclusion that rather than trusting jQueryUI to make my decisions for me, it was better for me to be a little more explicit with what I wanted by setting the dialog's height in the open event:

```
$(".shortTable").dialog({
    'height': '300',
    'width': '500',
    open: function (event, ui) {
        // Make sure the dialog will resize vertically 
        // if we are messing with the DOM elsewhere
        // (injecting/removing DOM elements)
        $(this).css("height", "auto");
    }
});
```

Of course instead of "auto" you could set a specific px measurement if it fits your needs but auto should allow it to size to whatever content you put in there including a table.

The open method will fire every time the dialog is opened so if you've re-written the dialog's content with some other jQuery validation or ajax content fetching it'll still be happy.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't that because you can't set height on table? There is no height attribute for table - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1. You can wrap table with div and then it works. Dialog contains scroll.

http://jsbin.com/omuzoq/2/edit

Comment: Good call, hadn't considered that tables don't have a height attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't the dialog object's height parameter control the height of the dialog window? When building a dialog, your selected element automatically gets wrapped in `<div class="ui-dialog-content"></div>` as part of the dialog rendering process.

Answer (score 0):

So basically when open the dialog the height attribute is getting replaced as the plugin  is adding its own height to it w.r.t. the screen size(you can check this by doing view source). so in order to use the computed height atttributes we need to disable all the styles added by this plugin

```
 $( "#dialog_confirm_message" ).dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                                                  $('#dialog_confirm_message').removeAttr('style');
                        },
                        minHeight: 104,
                        height: 120,
                        width: 520
                       });
```

Comment: I know this is old but i think its worth mentioned that by removing all the inline style will have a high chance to break the dialog since there's also some other style attribute besides than height such as `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add top NN in open block:

```
$( "#dlgEx" ).dialog({
    ...,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).dialog("option", "top", 10 );
    },
```